# How to fix this issue with undefined variable Node js?

Tags: node.js, express, momentjs

We are trying to convert these 3 birthday, birthmonth and birthyear variables into age. We are getting these 3 values from front end and want to convert them into age in node js backend and store in the user database. We use moment js for converting it into age.

```
module.exports = {
  async CreateUser(req, res) {
    const schema = Joi.object().keys({
      username: Joi.string()
        .required(),
      email: Joi.string()
        .email()
        .required(),
      password: Joi.string()
        .required(),
        birthday: Joi.number().integer()
        .required().min(2).max(2),
        birthmonth: Joi.number().integer()
        .required().min(2).max(2),
        birthyear: Joi.number().integer()
        .required(),
        age:age 
    });

    const { error, value } = Joi.validate(req.body, schema);
    if (error && error.details) {
      return res.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({ msg: error.details })
    }

    const userEmail = await User.findOne({
      email: Helpers.lowerCase(req.body.email)
    });
    if (userEmail) {
      return res
        .status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
        .json({ message: 'Email already exist' });
    }

    const userName = await User.findOne({
      username: Helpers.firstUpper(req.body.username)
    });
    if (userName) {
      return res
        .status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
        .json({ message: 'Username already exist' });
    }

    return bcrypt.hash(value.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) {
        return res
          .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
          .json({ message: 'Error hashing password' });
      }
     const age = moment().diff(moment([birthyear, birthmonth - 1, birthday]), 'years');

      const body = {
        username: Helpers.firstUpper(value.username),
        email: Helpers.lowerCase(value.email),
        birthday: (value.bday),
         birthmonth: (value.month),
       birthyear: (value.month),
        password: hash,
       age:age
      };
      User.create(body)
        .then(user => {
          const token = jwt.sign({ data: user }, dbConfig.secret, {
            expiresIn: '5h'
          });
          res.cookie('auth', token);
          res
            .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
            .json({ message: 'User created successfully', user, token });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res
            .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .json({ message: 'Error occured' });
        });
    });
  },
```

The error is appearing when I submit sign up button on front end on command prompth it shows birthyear is undefined and shows under this line:

```
const age = moment().diff(moment([birthyear, birthmonth - 1, birthday]),
```

which I placed above the body and inserted age:age inside body

I am sure the same error will happen for other 2 values as well. What is wrong? How can we fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never defined the variables `birthyear`, `birthmonth` or `birthmonth` anywhere in the code you provided, so the error makes sense.

I'm not familiar with the `Joi` object validation lib you are using, but seeing as `value.password` contains the password in the bcrypt call above, I think you can access these fields as properties on `value`. Try this:

```
 const age = moment().diff(moment([value.birthyear, value.birthmonth - 1, value.birthday]), 'years');
```

You will probably get similar errors in the `const body = {...}` block of code as you are using different property names than in your schema definition, so double check that all `value.*` lines to fix those.

Comment: Thanks for replying. In terms of body object age:age is correct right (last on in body object)?

Comment: @NewTechLover You may have to change it to `age: age.toDate()` as it's currently a `moment` date object which your database may not understand. `toDate` will convert it to a regular js Date object which should work (though that depends on the database and database library you are using)

Comment: I am using mongo DB mongoose

Comment: @NewTechLover Mongoose will work well with moment's `.toDate()`